# How to add and substract `Date` in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check a date with a particular days from now, so I wrote like this:

```
(Date.today + 2.days) - Date.today > 1.days
```

Contrary to my thought, this returns `false`.

I found out the problem caused by different type of classes.

```
[13] pry(main)> (Date.today - Date.today)
=> (0/1)
[14] pry(main)> (Date.today - Date.today).class
=> Rational
```

But I don't know how to circumvent the problem, does anyone knows how to add or subtract `Date` class?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: have a look at change method http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/change

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/220858). Ignore dates for a moment... ***What*** are you checking and ***what condition*** are you checking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add days, you might want simply to:

```
▶ (Date.today + 2) - Date.today > 1
# ⇒ true
▶ (Date.today + 2).class
# ⇒ Date < Object
▶ Date.today + 2
# ⇒ #<Date: 2014-11-09 ((2456971j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem you can do

```
Date.today + 2 - Date.today > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. The biggest mistake is that you are trying to compare objects which are not homogeneous.

On one side you have Dates and duration objects (2.days), on the other you have durations. It's like comparing cars with fruits.

```
(Date.today + 2.days) - Date.today > 1.days
```

One possible solution is to use the algebric property of the equation that allows you to add the same value to both sides of the equation.

```
Date.today + 2.days > Date.today + 1.days
```

The benefit is that you will compare two homogenous objects.

```
2.1.1 :005 > Date.today + 2.days > Date.today + 1.days
 => true
```

You can also write the same expression reusing the same time instance (which is very close to add and subtract the same `Date.today`, as you were doing)

```
time = Date.today
2.days.from_now(Date.time) > 1.days.from_now(time)
```